# como realizar correctamente esta condicional dentro de este for?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que realiza votes en la cadena de bloques de steemjs.

Mi codigo

```
var u = 0;
const friendsz = [
      'juan',
      'luis',
      'carlos'
    ];  
var myInt = setInterval(function () {

    if (u < friendsz.length) {
        //console.log(friendsz[u++]);
        wkd.api.getDiscussionsByBlog({tag: friendsz[u++], limit: 1}, (err, res) => { 
            var author = res[0].author;
            var permlink = res[0].permlink;
            console.log(author);
            console.log(permlink);

        wkd.api.getActiveVotes(author, permlink, (err, res) => {

        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            var post = res[i].voter;

        if (post == voter) {
            console.log("[Weku Buster Bot] says:".yellow, "The Post:", permlink, "of the user", author, "has already been voted.");
        }else{
            wkd.broadcast.vote(wif, voter, author, permlink, weight, (err, res) => { 
                console.log("[Weku Buster Bot] says: ".yellow + "Your Friend " + author + " Got " + weight/100 + "% Upvote For his last post.");
            });
            wkd.broadcast.comment(wifPosting, author, permlink, voter, comment_permlink, title, body, jsonMetadata, (err, res) => {
                console.log("[Weku Buster Bot] says: ".yellow + "We have announced to your friend " + author + " that you have voted his last post a weight: " + weight/100 + " %.");
        });
        }
        }
    });
    });
}

}, 15000);
```

EL problema que surge es que al realizar la comparación de post y user hace que que todo el if se ejecute y me causa errores.

post == voter verifica que el usuario ya ha votado si no ha votado, tendría que saltar a else y ejecutar las funciones. pero en este caso ejecuta las 2 cosas a la ves y me provoca errores. ¿Entonces como puedo hacer bien esa condicional?

Comment: que lenguaje es.. y no se entiende que queres?!?!????

Comment: olvide poner que era javascript. pues solo quiero realizar bien esa condicional.

Comment: Pero sigo sin entender cual es el problema. si esta haciendo lo que queres...

Comment: es que me trae a la  ves el else. se supone que "post == usuario" son correctos, no tendría que traerme el else. con traerme me refiero a mostrar.

Comment: me parece que estas entendiendo muy mal tu codigo. Si es correcto, el if muestra "son similares", si es incorrecto, muestra el else.. en tu array tenes 3 incorrectos y un correcto.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "no quiero que se ponga a iterar el else"? El condicional está bien. ¿Qué necesitas que haga? O ¿Qué está haciendo que tú dices que no quieres que haga? Porque en términos generales está todo bien. Si lo que quieres es que al conseguir un 'match' (post es igual a usuario) se detenga el bucle, entonces agrega un `break` despues del `console.log('son similares)`. Así ya no sigue verificando. Otra cosa. Saca tu `var usuario='miguel'` fuera del bucle. Decláralo antes de entrar al bucle. Saludos.

Comment: Si, la pregunta no es muy clara... muestras como funciona ahora... pero solo dices "quiero solucionar este condicional"... pero nunca específicas como estás esperando que funcione? que debería mostrar? o como debería procesar las cosas... no te has explicado bien

Comment: voy hacer otro post siendo mas especifico.

Comment: no @HadrienRivere.. no necesitas hacer otro post.. y hasta es incorrecto. apreta el boton [edit] y corregi esta pregunta. no hagas otra con este mismo tema...

Comment: No es necesario otro. Solo edita este y explicas un poco mejor. Con gusto te ayudamos.

Comment: echo :) este es real codigo

Comment: o saben de una manera de convertir a var post = res[i].voter; en variable global?

Comment: Aclaremos algo, `post == voter` ¿Dónde declaras `voter`?. Cuando dices que "todo el `if` se ejecute" exactamente ¿a qué te refieres? La condición va a depender de que `post` sea igual a `voter`, si eso ocurre hará una cosa, si eso no ocurre hará la otra. Y esa condición se verificará por cada iteración de tu bucle `for`. Tal vez no estás entendiendo la dinámica de tu propio código.

Comment: la verdad si no estaba entendiendo la dinámica de el codigo. ya el Compañero @gbianchi me abrió los ojos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca solo hay un error de concepto en el codigo.

Si tu for solo tiene que verificar si hay uno correcto, no deberias tener un if con un else adentro...

En realidad, lo que tendrias que hacer es comprobar si existe o no ese usuario en la cadena, y despues dependiendo de eso, hacer lo que queres hacer

Algo asi:

```
var encontrado = false;
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    var post = res[i].voter;
    if (post == voter) {
        encontrado = true;
    }
}
if (encontrado) {
    console.log("[Weku Buster Bot] says:".yellow, "The Post:", permlink, "of the user", author, "has already been voted.");
}else{
    wkd.broadcast.vote(wif, voter, author, permlink, weight, (err, res) => { 
    console.log("[Weku Buster Bot] says: ".yellow + "Your Friend " + author + " Got " + weight/100 + "% Upvote For his last post.");
 });
 ... todo el resto de tu codigo
```

De esta forma, solo comprobas si voto o no...

Es mas, como simplificacion, podrias no recorrer todo el array usando un while de la siguiente forma...

```
var encontrado = false;
var i = 0;
var tamaño = res.length
while (!encontrado && i < tamaño) {
    var post = res[i].voter;
    if (post == voter) {
        encontrado = true;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Como aclaración, este codigo es puro, porque las librerias que buscan dentro de arrays, hacen exactamente esto que escribi.

Comment: Excelente. Funciona correctamente ahora si. Gracias. Ahora tendré que repasar mas sobre esto.

Comment: paso algo bro. cuando ejecuto el programa si el primer post ya ha sido votado se queda con que los demás post han sido votados. es decir ya no ejecuta la función para verificar si ya ha sido votado o no cada post.

Comment: @HadrienRivere habria que ver como metiste este codigo dentro de tu funcion...

Comment: lo acabo de actulizar :p

Comment: Actualizar tu codigo en este caso es mala idea, porque la respuesta queda desactualizada.... sobre todo porque mi solucion ya no es la solucion porque es lo que escribiste.. volve atras el post.. el error es que var verifyVote = false; tiene que estar adentro de la funcion.. justo encima del for.. si no, una vez que es true, nadie lo vuelve a poner en false. @HadrienRivere

Comment: ya lo eh puesto como estaba. y finalmente ya funciona gracias.